# Could Run netflix conductor with postgress -

Tags: netflix, conductor, netflix-conductor, conductor-framework

I am trying to follow the simple tutorial of Netflix conductor but could not run the postgress or any other persistence option

I have got APPLICATION FAILED TO START and can not use the persistence option

conductor 3.9.10  using docker-compose
os: mac (also tried on windows)

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml -f docker-compose-postgres.yaml up`

```
conductor-server_1  | 5772 [main] WARN  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext [] - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'workflowResource' defined in URL [jar:file:/app/libs/conductor-server-3.10.0-SNAPSHOT-boot.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/conductor-rest-3.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/netflix/conductor/rest/controllers/WorkflowResource.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'workflowServiceImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/app/libs/conductor-server-3.10.0-SNAPSHOT-boot.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/conductor-core-3.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/netflix/conductor/service/WorkflowServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'workflowExecutor' defined in URL [jar:file:/app/libs/conductor-server-3.10.0-SNAPSHOT-boot.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/conductor-core-3.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/netflix/conductor/core/execution/WorkflowExecutor.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'deciderService' defined in URL [jar:file:/app/libs/conductor-server-3.10.0-SNAPSHOT-boot.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/conductor-core-3.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/netflix/conductor/core/execution/DeciderService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.netflix.conductor.dao.MetadataDAO' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
conductor-server_1  | 5782 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService [] - Stopping service [Tomcat]
conductor-server_1  | 5815 [main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener [] -
conductor-server_1  |
conductor-server_1  | Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
conductor-server_1  | 5853 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter [] -
conductor-server_1  |
conductor-server_1  | ***************************
conductor-server_1  | APPLICATION FAILED TO START
conductor-server_1  | ***************************
conductor-server_1  |
conductor-server_1  | Description:
conductor-server_1  |
conductor-server_1  | Parameter 2 of constructor in com.netflix.conductor.core.execution.DeciderService required a bean of type 'com.netflix.conductor.dao.MetadataDAO' that could not be found.
conductor-server_1  |
conductor-server_1  |
conductor-server_1  | Action:
conductor-server_1  |
conductor-server_1  | Consider defining a bean of type 'com.netflix.conductor.dao.MetadataDAO' in your configuration.
conductor-server_1  |
```

Answer (score 3):

If someone encountered this issue, the solution is to add the following under `server/build.gradle`:

```
runtimeOnly group: 'com.netflix.conductor', name: 'conductor-postgres-persistence', version: '3.9.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to your build.gradle file

```
runtimeOnly "com.netflix.conductor:conductor-postgres-persistence:3.9.10"
```

Replace 3.9.10 with the latest version if you checkout from the main branch